# vba excel 2003 copy range find and paste the selected range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro in excel sheet. In this macro, do I take a copy of the cell number (B04) and I search on the worksheet (3), but the problem that I am having is when I want to change the content of the cell macro is also searching for new content

---

```
Range("D6").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("3").Select
Cells.Find(What:="Yasser Arafat Ateya ELsayed EL", After:=ActiveCell, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Range("B6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ShowDetail = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Could you reword your question a little bit?  I'm confused.  
When you say copy cell (B04) you have "D6" being copied in the code.  
Could you break this down into steps, as if you were doing it manually, one step at a time, and then revise your question using that?   Leave the code up, it's very helpful.  Like, step 1: examine sheet("3").Range("B6").  step 2: take the value from that.  step 3: search for the value of that in Sheet("4"), or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

Going with the flow of your code, and with a bit of explanation to help you, amend your code to something like this.  Also learn about explicitly referencing separate worksheets in your code rather than relying on ActiveSheet.

```
Sub findSomeText()
'the find method returns a Range so define a variable to catch this
Dim fndrng As Range
'to search for different strings use a String variable
Dim srchStr As String

'get the srchStr (in this case from D6 in the ActiveSheet)
srchStr = ActiveSheet.Range("D6").Value
'use Sheets("3") - you don't need to select it
'note that this means a Sheet with a (Tab)NAME of "3", not necessarily the third sheet
    With Sheets("3")
        'explicitly set the ActiveCell to Find from
        Range("A1").Activate
        'apply the Find method, note use LookIn:=xlValues; use of srchStr and .Cells
        Set fndrng = .Cells.Find(What:=srchStr, After:=ActiveCell, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    End With
        'check if a match has been found
        If Not fndrng Is Nothing Then
            'your code if srchStr has been found goes here e.g. found value into cell B6
            Range("B6").Value = fndrng.Value
            ' perhaps use MsgBox "Found" to test?
        Else
            'your code if srchStr has NOT been found goes here
            MsgBox "Not Found"
        End If

End Sub
```